# Error en LOGIN no muestra error mail o contraseña

Tags: javascript, php, html

Estoy intentando que el login muestre los errores indicados en código:

- '1' : "Error de conexión".
- '2' : "Correo electrónico inválido".
- '3' : "Contraseña inválida".

pero no logro que los muestre.

Actualmente tengo un usuario creado a modo de prueba en la base de datos tal y como adjunto en la foto. Creo que el error se ha de tratar en sintaxis o en algún fallo con las rutas de los ficheros y carpetas ya que me cuesta mucho, no obstante adjunto capturas de la organización de ficheros y carpetas.

Estas son las carpetas:

[image: Carpetas]

Y esto el usuario:

[image: usuario]

```
<div class="main-content">
    <div class="content-page">
        <form action="login.php" method="POST">
            <h3> Iniciar sesión </h3>
            <input type="text" name="email_usuario" placeholder="Correo">
            <input type="password" name="password_usuario" placeholder="Contraseña">
            <?php
            if (isset($_GET['e'])){
                switch ($_GET['e']) {
                        case '1' :
                        echo '<p> Error de conexión </p>';
                        break;
                        case '2' :
                        echo '<p> Correo electrónico inválido </p>';
                        break;
                        case '3' :
                        echo '<p> Contraseña inválida </p>'; 
                        break;
                    
                    default:
                        
                        break;
                }
            }

             ?>
            <button type="submit">Acceder</button>
        </form>
    
</div>
</div>
```

---

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$email_usuario=$_POST['email_usuario'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE email_usuario='$email_usuario'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count!=0) {
        $password_usuario=$_POST['password_usuario'];
        if ($row['password_usuario']!=$password_usuario){
            header('Location: ../login.php?e=3'); // Contraseña invalida =e3

        } else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['codigo_usuario']=$row['codigo_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['email_usuario']=$row['email_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$row['nombre_usuario'];
            header ('Location: ../');

        }
        
    } else{
        header('Location: ../login.php?e=2');// Correo electronico invalido =e2
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ../login.php?e=1'); // Error de conexion = e1
}
```

Fotos del código **login.php**:

[image: index1]

[image: index2]

Y este es mi error en consola:

[image: error consola]

añado captura probando posible solución indicada en comentarios sin éxito:
[image: posiblesolucion]

código probado segun arkanis:

```html
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$email_usuario=$_POST['email_usuario'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE email_usuario='$email_usuario'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if ($result) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($count!=0) {
        $password_usuario=$_POST['password_usuario'];
        if ($row['password_usuario']!=$password_usuario){
            header('Location: ../login.php?e=3'); // Contraseña invalida =e3

         
    }else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['codigo_usuario']=$row['codigo_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['email_usuario']=$row['email_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$row['nombre_usuario'];
            
             $value = 1; //2
    $time = '0';
    $url = '../login.php'; //o puede ser index.php, a donde quieras reciba el error.
    $param = '?e='.$value;
    
    
    header('refresh:' . $time . ';url=' . $url . $param);
        
    } else{
        header('Location: ../login.php?e=2');// Correo electronico invalido =e2
    }
}else{
    header('Location: ../login.php?e=1'); // Error de conexion = e1
}
```

introducir el código aquí

Comment: Agrega el mensaje de error que te muestra

Comment: Muy buenas, realmente no me lanza ningún error en consola ni en la web, directamente lo que realiza es como si refrescase la página en vez de indicarme que el mail introducido o la contraseña es errónea

Comment: En tu navegador busca las opciones de desarrollador. Ej Chrome con f12 te muestra y ve a consola

Comment: Si si, lo había hecho pero lo único que me muestra es un error que llevo arrastrando tiempo atrás, no varía la consola una vez introducido los datos y dándole a acceder

Comment: te esta dando un `http 403` lo que implica que no tienes acceso, pueda que sea por permisos.

Comment: Por favor no agregues imágenes solo copia lo de la consola y expande lo del `POST` y copialo aca por favor.

Comment: Este es el mensaje que me indica: A page or script is accessing at least one of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform. Starting in Chrome 101, the amount of information available in the User Agent string will be reduced.
To fix this issue, replace the usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform with feature detection, progressive enhancement, or migrate to navigator.userAgentData.
Note that for performance reasons, only the first access to one of the properties is shown

Comment: No obstante ese error me lo mostraba mucho antes

Answer (score 0):

No deberias de usar:

```php
    header('Location: ...);
```

En su lugar deberias usar:

```php
    $value = 1; //2
    $time = '0';
    $url = '../login.php'; //o puede ser index.php, a donde quieras reciba el error.
    $param = '?e='.$value;
    
    
    header('refresh:' . $time . ';url=' . $url . $param);
```

[Documentacion de Refresh](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#97114)

Comment: Muy buenas, por desgracia continua sin mostrarme el error aún aplicando eso

Comment: Muy buenas acabo de subir una captura con la posible solución que has propuesto ( por si la he entendido mal o algo ) no obstante continúa sin funcionar :(

Comment: @Victorhl8 lo siento mio celular no carga imagenes... deberias colocar todo el codigo que uses en texto incluyendo mensajes de error etc.

Comment: lo que he probado ha sido en mi código eliminar el header('Location: ...) y pegar literal el fragmento de código tuyo no obstante continúa sin mostrarme el error, simplemente se me refresca la página, imagino que te refieres a eso verdad?

Comment: acabo de añadir en la propia publicación el código tal y como entiendo que te refieres ( Sin foto ) a ver si así puedes comprobar que era eso a lo que te referías

Comment: si y no, cuando te dije usa refresh es que remplaces los else { header.... location con la opcion de refresh...

Answer (score -1):

Creo que simplemente deberías cambiar login.php por index.php

```php
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$email_usuario=$_POST['email_usuario'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE email_usuario='$email_usuario'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
if (true) {
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $count=1;
    if ($count!=0) {
        $password_usuario=$_POST['password_usuario'];
        if (true){
            header('Location: index.php?e=3'); // Contraseña invalida =e3

        } else{
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['codigo_usuario']=$row['codigo_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['email_usuario']=$row['email_usuario'];
            $_SESSION['nombre_usuario']=$row['nombre_usuario'];
            header ('Location: ./');

        }
        
    } else{
        header('Location: index.php?e=2');// Correo electronico invalido =e2
    }
}else{
    header('Location: index.php?e=1'); // Error de conexion = e1
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy buenas Jesús, lo he realizado pero continúa sin mostrar el mensaje, adjunto 2 capturas del código por si puede ayudaros, muchas gracias!